# Customizing tableheader.js Sticky table Header

Tags: javascript, theming

As I am having a custom "position:fixed" top navigation bar in my admin pages, the sticky table header are being hidden behind it when I scroll-up.

I went through tableheader.js and saw there is a Drupal.settings.tableHeaderOffset that helps change the "top" property, but I don't know where I should override it. Possible to do it in my template.php?

Also, I would like to change the position that triggers the sticky header to change visibility from hidden to visible...

```
  // Track horizontal positioning relative to the viewport and set visibility.
  var hScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
  var vOffset = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) - this.vPosition;
  this.stickyVisible = vOffset > 0 && vOffset < this.vLength;
  this.stickyTable.css({ left: (-hScroll + this.hPosition) + 'px', visibility: this.stickyVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override tableheader.js using `hook_js_alter(&js) {}`, just replace path of file, like in example ([details here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7)).

Also you can override `Drupal.settings.tableHeaderOffset` value.
Thus, in template.php place something like this:

```
drupal_add_js('themeTableHeaderOffset() { return 200; }', 'inline');
drupal_add_js(array('tableHeaderOffset' => 'themeTableHeaderOffset'), 'setting');
```

Comment: I ended up using hook_js_alter to replace the default misc/tableheader.js file with a custom one in my theme, but your solution seems to answer to my question on why when I used 'setting' and did 'tableHeaderOffset' => '200' I got a "number is not a function" error msg. I guess that's the way to circumvent it..

Comment: Just take a look in tableheader.js on line 83:

`this.stickyOffsetTop = Drupal.settings.tableHeaderOffset ? eval(Drupal.settings.tableHeaderOffset + '()') : 0;`

There is eval expression, so `Drupal.settings.tableHeaderOffset` should be a callback function name, like in my example. Obviously `200()` is not a function :)

Comment: Yep, I'd seen it, I just didn't think about it myself :) thanks!

Comment: Actually I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: themeTableHeaderOffset is not defined`. (I put it in a preprocess page) should I `if` to check if the tableheader.js is loaded..

Comment: Fixed it like that:`drupal_add_js('var themeTableHeaderOffset = function() { var offsetheight = jQuery("#header").height(); return offsetheight; }', 'inline');`

Comment: Plz mark as correct answer :)

Comment: Although the code as posted did not work, I'll accept as it was in the right direction.

Comment: Why not updating the posted code with the working one?